# angular2-switcher is not working and giving error - command 'extension.switchTemplate' not found

Tags: angular

I am using angular extension angular2-switcher.
I use Alt + o to navigate to TS file from html. It used to work but now getting below issue on trying Alt+o.

**command 'extension.switchTemplate' not found**
[image: issue with angular2-switcher]

Comment: did you try to reinstall?
if so try to contact the extension developer

Comment: reinstalling does not worked

Comment: It is working now, not did any thing specific. May be restart of machine got it fixed.